# Django get_FIELD_display

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to access data.get_age_display in my email template. I can't seem to get the display of this. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I've using get_FIELD_display numerous times before but passed as context to a normal template. Is there something different with forms?

```
class RequestForm(forms.Form):

    ADULT = 1
    SENIOR = 2
    STUDENT = 3

    AGE_GROUP = (
        (ADULT, 'Adult'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
        (STUDENT, 'Student'),
    )


    name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=15)
    age = forms.ChoiceField(choices=AGE_GROUP)
    details = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())

    def save(self):
        order = Order(
            name = self.cleaned_data['name'],
            phone = self.cleaned_data['phone'],
            age = self.cleaned_data['age'],
            details = self.cleaned_data['details'],
        )
        order.save()

        template = loader.get_template('request_email.txt')

        # send over the order object in an email extracted so they can handle the ticket order
        context = Context({
            'data': order,
        })

        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

        email_subject = 'Request Tickets'
        mail_managers(email_subject, template.render(context))
```

in my request_email.txt all I am doing is {{ data.get_age_display }} any ideas?

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown the code for the Order model that you're creating. Are you sure that the `age` field on the model has `choices` set?

Any reason you're not using a ModelForm? You're creating an `Order` object within the form's `save()` method, but not returning it. A modelform would do that for you, as well as removing the need to redeclare the fields for the form.

Comment: Daniel, I omitted some code for simplicity, modelform would not be good for what I am doing. Here is the code for the order model

Comment: class Order(models.Model):

    ADULT = 1
    SENIOR = 2
    STUDENT = 3

    AGE_GROUP = (
        (ADULT, 'Adult'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
        (STUDENT, 'Student'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    age = models.IntegerField(choices=AGE_GROUP)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is coming WAAAAAY later than the question being posted but here's my answer for completeness and anyone else who might benefit from it  :-)

I'm going to assume that in AGE_GROUP, ADULT, SENIOR and STUDENT are integers. Your form cleaning will NOT automatically clean the string contained in the POST and return an integer. So in this code:

```
context = Context({
    'data': order,
})
```

you would think order.age is referring to an integer but that is, in fact, incorrect. It's burned me a few times before because this **will** correctly save the integer to the physical table, but the order instance still has the string representation of the age field.

You could do one of two things:
1. Clean this in the field:

```
clean_age(self):  
    return int(self.cleaned_data['age'])
```

or create a new field type:

```
def MyChoiceField(forms.ChoiceField):  
    def clean(self, value):  
        if not value:  
            if self.required:  
                raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['required'])  
                return None  
            else:  
                return None  
        return int(value)
```

link that to the form field:

```
age = MyChoiceField(choices=AGE_GROUP)
```

and then you'll be able to apply this logic to any other such choice field in future. Personally, I find the latter approach the best one and I stick all my custom field types into a form_utils file so that I can use them everywhere. Another gotcha is that forms.charField doesn't automatically strip the entered text and you can use this approach to fix that too.